# Почему виснет Windows Form

Tags: c#

В принципе я понимаю, все дело в потоках. Пишу программу, которая парсит большой XML.
В начале она загружает zip файл и затем распаковывает находящийся внутри xml, код конечно не мой и поэтому наверное форма не виснет при его исполнении.

```
namespace FenixBookParser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string educational_lit_url = "zipurl"


        public static string files_path = @"C:\Parser\1139697.zip";
        WebClient webClient;
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        Parser LoadXml = new Parser();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void Download_Unzip_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Download_Unzip_Btn.Enabled = false;
            if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\Parser\"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Parser\");
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.Delete(@"C:\Parser\", true);
            }
            DownloadFile(educational_lit_url);
        }

        public void DownloadFile(string urlAddress)
        {

            using (webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);


                Uri Uri = new Uri(urlAddress);

                sw.Start();

                try
                {
                    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(Uri, files_path);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            labelSpeed.Text = string.Format("{0} kb/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));

            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

            labelPerc.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";

            labelDownloaded.Text = string.Format("{0} MB's / {1} MB's",
                (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"),
                (e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"));
        }

        private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            sw.Reset();
            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Загрузка была отменена");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Загружено и распаковано");
                button1.Enabled = true;
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(files_path, @"C:\Parser\");
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadXml.ReadXML(@"C:\Parser\1139697.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Тут много моего говнокодерства ну все же буду рад любому вашему совету. Так вот с эти кодом проблем нет, но как я только запускаю чтение XML

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadXml.ReadXML(@"C:\Parser\1139697.xml");
}
```

Программа работает и читает все, но форма на мертво виснет.

```
public async void ReadXML(string xml)
        {
            try
            {
                last_record_in_db = context.Books.OrderByDescending(b => b.BookId).FirstOrDefault()?.Book_id_ozon;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("не могу подключиться к базе данных");
            }

            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Async = true;
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD;
            settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
            int start_record = 0;

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xml, settings))
            {
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        if (reader.Name == "offer")
                        {
                            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                            xmlDoc.LoadXml(reader.ReadOuterXml());
                            XmlNode book_node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("offer");

                            if (start_record == 1 || last_record_in_db == null)
                            {
                                start_record = 1;
                                RecordFromOzonToDB(book_node);
                            }

                            int ozon_book_id = Convert.ToInt32(book_node.Attributes["id"].Value);
                            //Как только последняя запись в базе станет ровна записи из XML при его чтении
                            //Начинаем догружать данные в базу
                            if (last_record_in_db == ozon_book_id)
                            {
                                //Начинается запись со следующей итерации
                                start_record = 1;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Сам метод чтения XML  я его сделал асинхронным думал это поможет, но увы.
Так вот, кто на пальцах объяснит, как работать с потоками и что мне сделать с этим методом, чтобы он не вешал всю форму? 
Код
http://pastebin.com/X8uF2dfd

Добавляю пример XML

```
 <offer id="146881" type="book" available="true" group_id="146881">
        <url>http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/146881/?from=prt_xml_facet</url>
        <price>379</price>
        <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>
        <categoryId>1137636</categoryId>
        <picture>http://static.ozone.ru/multimedia/books_covers/1004510046.jpg</picture>
        <store>false</store>
        <pickup>true</pickup>
        <delivery>true</delivery>
        <local_delivery_cost>299</local_delivery_cost>
        <author>Лаура Камбурнак</author>
        <name>Атлас животных</name>
        <publisher>Русич</publisher>
        <year>2004</year>
        <ISBN>978-5-8859-0680-7</ISBN>
        <language>Русский</language>
        <binding>70x108/8</binding>
        <page_extent>48</page_extent>
        <table_of_contents>Атлас животных</table_of_contents>
        <description>Предназначенная для детей в возрасте от 5 до 8 лет, эта красочная книга позволит им открыть для себя богатейший животный мир нашей планеты. Рассматривая цветные картинки, каждая из которых сопровождается пояснительным текстом, юные читатели познакомятся на страницах атласа с фауной всех шести континентов нашей планеты. Они узнают много нового, порой необычного и удивительного, и смогут представить зверей, рыб и птиц в условиях их естественной среды обитания.</description>
        <sales_notes>Бесплатная доставка при заказе от 3500 рублей</sales_notes>
        <barcode>9785885906807</barcode>
        <weight>0.667</weight>
        <dimensions>1.000/27.000/33.300</dimensions>
        <param name="Вес" unit="г">667</param>
        <param name="Ширина упаковки" unit="мм">270</param>
        <param name="Высота упаковки" unit="мм">333</param>
        <param name="Глубина упаковки" unit="мм">10</param>
      </offer>
```

Comment: Приведите пример вашего xml-файла (или дайте ссылку). Как уже написали в ответе, одна из причин подвисания формы - загрузка в `XmlDocument`, другая причина - работа с БД (судя по названию метода `*ToDB`). Также укажите технологию, используемую для работы с БД.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Xml очень большого размера, поэтому использую reader. Выложу весь код на пастербин

Comment: насколько большого, сколько это в гигабайтах? Работа с БД может очень сильно тормозить, если реализована без расчета на количество данных

Comment: В вашем коде xml асинхронно (что хорошо) читается, пока не встретится узел `offer` и этот узел (узлы) синхронно (что плохо) загружается в `XmlDocument` и потом в БД. Напишите хотя бы примерный размер этих узлов `offer` (в строках или байтах).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov добавил XML

Comment: А что делает `RecordFromOzonToDB`? Если его временно закомментировать, станет быстро?

Comment: @VladD  Добавил весь код в pasterbin ссылка выше.

Comment: @shatoidil: `context.SaveChanges();` на каждой итерации — это может быть медленно. Попробуйте убрать работу с базой, чтобы проверить, проблема именно в этом или нет.

Comment: @VladD А как мне тогда записывать данные в базу?

Comment: @shatoidil: Ну, если проблема и правда в этом, то её мы как-нибудь решим. А если не в этом, то будем искать корень проблемы дальше.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47233/discussion-between-shatoidil-and-vladd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расследование показало, что проблема в большом количестве XML-данных, а также в обращении к базе данных на каждой итерации.

В качестве простого решения имеет смысл выполнять `LoadXml.ReadXML` в отдельном потоке:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => LoadXml.ReadXML(@"C:\Parser\1139697.xml"));
}
```

Имеет смысл также попробовать накопить разобранные книги в массив, и добавлять в базу всё сразу, в один присест.

Comment: Хотелось бы комментарий от поставившего минус.

Answer (score 0):

Несмотря на то, что вы добавили async к методу ReadXML, это не значит что он выполнится асинхронно, попробуйте возвращаемый тип сделать Task(у ReadXML) а также добавить async к обработчику клика, и await соответственно внутри обработчика

Comment: Асинхронно != в отдельном потоке

Comment: @PashaPash то есть несколько асинхронных действий могут происходить в одном потоке?

Comment: да. асинхронность через async/await подразумевает, что *вообще весь код* выполняется в одном потоке (что убирает необходимость делать invoke и думать о синхронизации). но за счет магии этот поток освобождается на время ожидания ответа от железа (диска) и от сетевых ресурсов.

Comment: в отдельный поток код можно выбросить через Task.Run (как в ответе от VladD)

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо, не знал